# Delay run an After update trigger

Tags: trigger, future, before-trigger, trigggers

I have two after update triggers T1 , T2.
Can I do their run sequencial so that T2 should run always after T1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would go through Trigger best practices.

- Always use handling classes.
- Logic should be in Apex classes not in
  Trigger.
- **And use one Trigger per object.**

We say it Trigger Framework:

Example (Assume a trigger on Opportunity):

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

  if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
    OpportunityTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert();
  } else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    OpportunityTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert();
  }

}
```

Handler (Has business logic):

```
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

  public OpportunityTriggerHandler() {}

  /* context overrides */

  public static void handleAfterInsert() {
    setLostOppsToZero(); // It is Your T1
    setLostOppsToSecondZero(); // It is your T2
  }

  /* private methods */

  private void setLostOppsToZero() {
    for(Opportunity o: (List<Opportunity>) Trigger.new) {
      if(o.StageName == 'Closed Lost' && o.Amount > 0) {
        o.Amount = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  private void setLostOppsToSecondZero() {
    for(Opportunity o: (List<Opportunity>) Trigger.new) {
      if(o.StageName == 'Closed Lost' && o.Amount > 0) {
        o.Amount = 10;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Go through following URL as well: [Apex Trigger Best Practice](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)